No such file or directory,
name: Android Build and Upload to App Center

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      
      - name: Clean the project
        run: ./gradlew clean  

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

      - name: List files in build/outputs/apk/debug
        run: ls -la app/build/outputs/apk/debug

      - name: Generate build artifact name
        id: generate-artifact-name
        run: |
          ARTIFACT_NAME=app-debug-$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').apk
          echo "ARTIFACT_NAME=$ARTIFACT_NAME" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Archive artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: ${{ env.ARTIFACT_NAME }}
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

      - name: Install App Center CLI
        run: npm install -g appcenter-cli

      - name: List files before upload to App Center
        run: ls -la app/build/outputs/apk/debug

      - name: Upload APK to App Center
        env:
          APP_CENTER_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.APP_CENTER_API_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          if [ -f "app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk" ]; then
            appcenter distribute release \
              --file app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk \
              --app ${{ secrets.APP_CENTER_OWNER_NAME }}/$(echo ${{ secrets.APP_CENTER_APP_NAME }} | sed 's/ /-/g') \
              --group "Collaborators" \
              --token $APP_CENTER_API_TOKEN
          else
            echo "APK file not found!"
            exit 1
          fi

This is my script for workflow in github action I am getting error.

Error: Command 'distribute release --file app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --app / --group Collaborators --token ***' failed with exception "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'"
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.

When we execute ./gradlew assembleDebug  in android studio I am able to generate folder but when I execute from work flow its not creating path can any one help me how to execute or from where we can pick apk file .

Is this yml file? If yes then can you print and share output of command `- name: Print Working Directory
run: pwd
  - name : List Files
    run: ls 

  - name: Clean the project
    run: ./gradlew clean`

